# Creating denormalized tables with triggers too slow

Tags: postgresql, triggers, amazon-rds, denormalized

Assume I'm doing everything in one postgresql database. I have 10 source tables I'm using to create one huge denormalized table. These source tables change frequently and have triggers firing after insert/update/delete to modify denormalized table in near-real-time. The problem is, some of these source tables I'm joining are huge (one table has 120M and other 25M rows) and statements for inserting new rows into denormalized table execute for a long time (20+ minutes for 50-100k rows).

So, I was thinking on what would be the best solution for updating(IUD)changes on this denormalized table, based on changes coming to source tables? Should I run these operations on a schedule, should I dedicate a specific database replica just for this, or should I continue trying to use triggers?

I'm open to using a totally different approach, as long as it's doable on the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like there is no good and simple solution.

Perhaps you don't need that one huge denormalized table, and denormalizing a few attributes would be good enough for your query speed.

If not, you will probably need a kind of data warehouse for the denormalized data, and refresh that daily with increments. Ideally, tables there are already pre-aggregated.